# can't run tomcat java: Permission denied

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I type `sh startup.sh` in terminal `ubuntu` I find below log and my tomcat server doesn't start. I can run `server` from `eclipse ide` but I can't run it from terminal.sudo sh startup.sh worked. Thanks to all of you to provide me answer previously It is worked fine. Now another problem is that mvn clean install is not worked previously it is also worked now it told The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
This also work fine in eclipse ?

```
 INFO: Server startup in 5732 ms
 20 Jan, 2014 7:39:54 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol pause
 INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
 20 Jan, 2014 7:39:54 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
 20 Jan, 2014 7:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
 INFO: Stopping service Catalina
         ./catalina.sh: 1: eval: /opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java: Permission denied
         ./catalina.sh: 1: eval: /opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java: Permission denied
```

Comment: are you starting as a root user ?

Comment: please use `sudo service tomcat start` in ubuntu, or login as Root user then `service tomcat start`

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld /opt/jdk1.6.0_23` and `ls -l /opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java`. I suspect your Java installation has been upgraded but you have an outdated environment variable.

Comment: sudo sh startup.sh worked. Thanks to all of you to provide me answer previously It is worked fine. Now another problem is that mvn clean install is not worked previously it is also worked now it told The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
This also work fine in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo sh startup.sh worked. Thanks to all of you to provide me answer previously It is worked fine with only sh startup.sh. It is java permision problem i find now i set full permission on java it is work with sh startup.sh as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `catalina.sh` script starts the tomcat instance by running something like this:

```
eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" <lots of options> ...
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
  >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

where `$_RUNJAVA` has previously been set to the pathname to a Java executable.

Now this is apparently failing, saying "/opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java: Permission denied"

This can mean a few things:

- The `/opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java` file does not exist with that pathname.  (This could possibly be due to a broken symlink ...)
- The `/opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java` file does exist, but it is not executable by the current (effective) user.
- The `/opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java` file does exist, but the current user is barred from accessing it because of permissions on some *directory* in the pathname.
- (If you are using SELinux/enforcing ... or equivalent), the policy is configured to not allow that executable to be executed in that context.

So ...:

- Check what effective user you are actually using to launch Tomcat.
- Check that the file exists at that location.  (Perhaps you installed a newer Java at a different location.)
- Check that it is executable by that user.
- Check the path to the file.
- If you are using SELinux (or equivalent), check the security logs for events corresponding to this.

If the problem is that you are using the wrong Java installation, then the "fix" will depend on how you are running `catalina.sh`.  If you are running it by hand from a shell, make sure that `JAVA_HOME` is set and exported correctly in your shell.  If you are running `catalina.sh` from an "init" script, check what the script is doing ...

---

(It is unlikely that this is anything to do with permissions on `catalina.sh` itself.)

Comment: sudo sh startup.sh worked. Thanks to all of you to provide me answer previously It is worked fine. Now another problem is that mvn clean install is not worked previously it is also worked now it told The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
This also work fine in eclipse ?

Comment: 1) Install the "maven" package then!! 2) It most likely works in Eclipse because you are using an Eclipse with built-in Maven support.  Look in the eclipse plugins directory ...

Comment: It is problem related with permission of opt folder in ubuntu. Now it is work fine thanks.